# Connecting a local Elixir/Erlang to a running application inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, networking, erlang, elixir, epmd

I've got an Elixir application running inside a Docker container (in my laptop). The Elixir application was executed with the following command:

```
iex \
  --name test@1.2.3.4 \
  --cookie secret \
  --erl '-kernel inet_dist_listen_min 9000'  \
  --erl '-kernel inet_dist_listen_max 9000' \
  -S mix phx.server
```

And the Docker container exposes the following ports:

`0.0.0.0:4000->4000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4369->4369/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp`

- 4000 for the Phoenix server
- 4369 for EPMD
- 9000 for the VM node

Then I try to connect using an IEx shell using the following command:

`iex --name local@127.0.0.1 --cookie secret` which results in this error:
`Protocol 'inet_tcp': register/listen error: epmd_close`

This seems to be because the local `epmd` daemon is trying to allocate to port 4369, however, this is already allocated to the Docker container.

I then changed the EPMD port like so:

`ERL_EPMD_PORT=4370 iex --name local@127.0.0.1 --cookie secret`

and I manage to open up the IEx session. However, I cannot find the node running on the Docker container:

```
iex(local@127.0.0.1)1> Node.connect :'test@1.2.3.4'
false
```

I'm not sure how to solve this. I was following this [blog post](https://crypt.codemancers.com/posts/2017-11-22-elixir-remote-debugging/).

Comment: Not sure if it applies but this previous [S O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351882/how-to-connect-two-elixir-nodes-via-local-network) may have some bearing on your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't an easier solution be to change the outward port of the docker container? Just change it to something like `4368`

```
$ docker run -itd -p 4000:4000 4368:4369 9000:9000 <docker_image_name> iex \
  --name test@1.2.3.4 \
  --cookie secret \
  --erl '-kernel inet_dist_listen_min 9000'  \
  --erl '-kernel inet_dist_listen_max 9000' \
  -S mix phx.server`
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't seem to help with the issue

Comment: can you specify a port for the node to connect to? Like: `iex(local@127.0.0.1)1> Node.connect :'test@1.2.3.4:4368'`