# How to configure docker to expose an Erlang node?

Tags: docker, erlang, epmd

I wrote a simple docker image which starts up an Erlang node (`rebar3` release, `console` launch mode). It starts fine and lets me ping the node from within the container. However, I can't get `erl` shell to ping it from the **host** — it simply returns `pang` and nothing is logged in the dockerized console.

The `Dockerfile` just starts the node, it doesn't do anything more interesting.

---

###### Checklist

- Cookie is set and matches
- `sname` is set on both nodes
- Docker node is reachable from other container nodes
- I refer to the docker node using full sname (tried `nodename@localhost`, `nodename@machinename` and `nodename@127.0.0.1`)
- `epmd` port is exposed (tried without it as well)

---

What could I have forgotten to make it work?

Comment: I think you also need to expose the port that the Erlang node listens for distribution connections on. Usually that's a random port number, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49012333/113848) illustrates how to set it to 9000. For the node name, it needs to be exactly the same as `node()` returns in the target node, _and_ the hostname needs to resolve to the right IP address.

Comment: Once you get to the point where it can establish a network connection, it might be useful to call `net_kernel:verbose(1).` before calling `net_adm:ping` - it turns on verbose logging of connection attempts.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** This answer is valid for Linux systems. Also, I think that the first and last options are the easiest

There are several ways to do so, but before, let's set some key ideas:

1. The following script is run inside docker simulating a node, it just waits for a node connection, prints it and terminates.

```bash
SCRIPT_RUN_IN_DOCKER='ok = net_kernel:monitor_nodes(true), fun F() -> receive {nodeup, N} -> io:format("Connected to ~p~n", [N]), init:stop() end end().'
```

2. In order for the distribution protocol to succeed, not only the node needs to be reached at the name used for the ping, the whole node name must match.
3. Erlang's `-node` can be used with IP, it will be used extensively in the following commands

## Options

Now, let's get with the options (All the commands are to be run in different terminals)

### Docker: Host network namespace

When starting docker in host's network namespace (`--net=host`), there's no difference with running both outside of docker (for network purposes). It's the easiest way to connect both nodes using plain docker.

- -name (ip):

  ```
   $> docker run --net=host erlang erl -noinput -name foo@127.0.0.1 -setcookie cookie -eval $SCRIPT_RUN_IN_DOCKER
   Connected to 'bar@127.0.0.1'

   $> erl -noinput -name bar@127.0.0.1 -setcookie cookie -eval "net_adm:ping('foo@127.0.0.1'), init:stop()."
  ```
- -sname with @localhost:

  ```
   $> docker run --net=host erlang erl -noinput -sname foo@localhost -setcookie cookie -eval $SCRIPT_RUN_IN_DOCKER
   Connected to bar@localhost

   $> erl -noinput -sname bar@localhost -setcookie cookie -eval "net_adm:ping('foo@localhost'), init:stop()."
  ```
- -sname with @$(hostname -f):

  ```
   $> docker run --net=host erlang erl -noinput -sname foo -setcookie cookie -eval $SCRIPT_RUN_IN_DOCKER
   Connected to 'bar@amazing-hostname'

   $> erl -noinput -sname bar -setcookie cookie -eval "net_adm:ping('foo@$(hostname -f)'), init:stop()."
  ```

### Docker: Using docker's default bridge (`docker0`)

By default, docker starts the containers in its own bridge, and these ips can be reached without need to expose any port.

`ip a show docker0` lists 172.17.0.1/16 for my machine, and erlang listens in 172.17.0.2 (shown in `docker inspect <container>`)

- -name (ip):

  ```
   $> docker run erlang erl -noinput -name foo@172.17.0.2 -setcookie cookie -eval $SCRIPT_RUN_IN_DOCKER
   Connected to bar@baz

   $> erl -noinput -name bar@baz -setcookie cookie -eval "net_adm:ping('foo@172.17.0.2'), init:stop()."
  ```
- -sname (fake name resolving to container ip):

  ```
   # The trick here is to have exactly the same node name for the destination, otherwise the distribution protocol won't work.
   # We can achieve the custom DNS resolution in linux by editing /etc/hosts

   $> tail -n 1 /etc/hosts
   172.17.0.2 erlang_in_docker

   $> docker run erlang erl -noinput -name foo@erlang_in_docker -setcookie cookie -eval $SCRIPT_RUN_IN_DOCKER
   Connected to 'bar@amazing-hostname'

   $> erl -noinput -sname bar -setcookie cookie -eval "net_adm:ping('foo@erlang_in_docker'), init:stop()."
  ```

### Docker: Using some other docker bridge

Just create the new network and repeat the previous steps, using the ips from the new network

```
docker network create erlang_docker_network
docker inspect erlang_docker_network
```

### Docker: Exposing ports with two EPMDs

When exposing ports you have to juggle ports and ips because the EPMD ports must be the same.

In this case you are going to have two epmds, one for the host and other for the container (EPMD rejects name requests from non-local peers), listening in the same port number.

The trick here is (ab)using the 127.0.0.* ips that point all to localhost to simulate different nodes. Note the flag to set the distribution port, as mentioned by @legoscia

- -name (ip):

  ```
   $> epmd -address 127.0.0.1

   $> docker run -p 127.0.0.2:4369:4369/tcp -p 127.0.0.2:9000:9000/tcp erlang erl -noinput -name foo@127.0.0.2 -setcookie cookie -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 9000 -kernel inet_dist_listen_max 9000 -eval $SCRIPT_RUN_IN_DOCKER
   Connected to bar@baz

   $> erl -noinput -name bar@baz -setcookie cookie -eval "net_adm:ping('foo@127.0.0.2'), init:stop()."
  ```
- -sname (fake name resolving to 127.0.0.2)

  ```
   And here we need again the DNS resolution provided by /etc/hosts

   $> tail -n 1 /etc/hosts
   127.0.0.2 erlang_in_docker

   $> epmd -address 127.0.0.1

   $> docker run -p 127.0.0.2:4369:4369/tcp -p 127.0.0.2:9000:9000/tcp erlang erl -noinput -name foo@erlang_in_docker -setcookie cookie -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 9000 -kernel inet_dist_listen_max 9000 -eval $SCRIPT_RUN_IN_DOCKER
   Connected to bar@baz

   $> erl -noinput -sname bar@baz -setcookie cookie -eval "net_adm:ping('foo@erlang_in_docker'), init:stop()."
  ```

### Docker-compose

`docker-compose` allows you to easily set up multi-container systems. With it, you don't need to create/inspect networks.

Given the following `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: '3.3'

services:
  node:
    image: "erlang"
    command:
      - erl
      - -noinput
      - -sname
      - foo
      - -setcookie
      - cookie
      - -eval
      - ${SCRIPT_RUN_IN_DOCKER} # Needs to be exported
    hostname: node

  operator:
    image: "erlang"
    command:
      - erl
      - -noinput
      - -sname
      - baz
      - -setcookie
      - cookie
      - -eval
      - "net_adm:ping('foo@node'), init:stop()."
    hostname: operator
```

If you run the following `docker-compose run` commands, you'll see the results:

```
$> docker-compose up node
Creating network "tmp_default" with the default driver
Creating tmp_node_1 ... done
Attaching to tmp_node_1
node_1      | Connected to baz@operator
tmp_node_1 exited with code 0

$> docker-compose run operator
```