# How do I make two Elixir applications(server & client) communicate with Phoenix.PubSub?

Tags: elixir, publish-subscribe

I have two applications, both in `Elixir`, that need to communicate with each other:

- 1 Server that has a `PubSub` with 2 `topics`, it broadcasts to one `topic` and listens to the other `topic`.
- 1 Client, that should subscribe to the Servers `PubSub` `topic` and `broadcast` to the other `topic`.

The scenario I want to get is that I start the Server, and then start one or multiple Clients that can subscribe to the server.

It just needs to work locally in the terminal, so it doesn't need any fancy.

The Server uses `:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 2.1"` and the rest is mostly a `Genserver` for message-handling.

The client is basically just a `Genserver` that only needs to subscribe to the server and sends A message when it receives one.

Any tips how I can make them talk?

Comment: I would start by looking at this: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_pubsub/Phoenix.PubSub.html#module-adapters , for this to work, you will need to connect the nodes first.

Comment: @Daniel yes i have read though the docs a couple of times but think it’s pretty slim on information, and I have hard time understanding how it is working. I understand that I need to connect the nodes I’m just very unsure how to do it.

Comment: this should cover everything you need to connect nodes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17360786/8103819

Comment: @Elmseld while it may be useful to familiarize yourself with manually connecting nodes by hand, it'll be impractical to do so. You can also check [Peerage](https://hexdocs.pm/peerage/readme.html#usage) to streamline the node connecting part, even locally. It works out of the box with Phoenix.PubSub.G2. After you're able to connect the nodes, [broadcast!/4](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_pubsub/Phoenix.PubSub.html#broadcast!/4) will be able to send messages across connected nodes.